# VHDL signal affectation simplification

Tags: signals, vhdl

I am pretty new to VHDL, and I have a stupid question.

I have in my code a huge case statement, and a signal that is a value (say '1') in only 1 case, and '0' in all other cases.
I would like to avoid to write th my_signal <= '0' in all the cases but the one where it is affected to 1 (for code readability/density/duplication)

For readability, I would like to keep this signal affectation in this process.

What I would like to do is something like

```
my_signal <='0';  
case  
case0  
....  
case1  
....  
case2  
my_signal <='1';  
....  
case3  
....  
case4  
....
```

to avoid having

```
case  
case0  
my_signal <='0';  
....  
case1  
my_signal <='0';  
....  
case2  
my_signal <='1';  
....  
case3  
my_signal <='0';  
....  
case4  
my_signal <='0';  
....
```

But this looks like a multidriven signal to me.
What is the clean way do achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As long as both assignment statements are in the same process, there is only one driver. Your first example is fine.

Comment: Thanks Brian ! Then I guess I can use this "default" to make my code lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

i) *default assignment*:

```
....
my_signal <='0';
case ...
  when case2 =>
    my_signal <='1';
    ....
end case;
```

ii) the *others* branch:

```
case ...
  when case2 =>
    my_signal <='1';
    ....
  when others =>
    my_signal <='0';
end case;
....
```

Choice (ii) is probably more useful, because a `case` statement in VHDL demands that all the possibilities are included, so with choice (i), you would probably need a `when others =>` branch anyway just to satisfy that condition, ie (i) would have to be:

```
....
my_signal <='0';
case ...
  when case2 =>
    my_signal <='1';
    ....
  when others =>
    null;         -- do nothing
end case;
```

Neither your original suggestion nor my suggestions have "multidriven" signals. You can drive (*assign to*) a signal as many times as you like *from one process* and it is never a "multidriven" signal. Any assignment to a signal in a process results in a driver on that signal. You only get a "multidriven" signal if you assign to a signal *from more than one process*, which you are not doing. When a line of code with a signal assignment (`<=`) is executed, what actually happens is an *event* is placed on the *event queue* (the simulators "To Do List"). That event will take place on the next *delta cycle* (or *simulation cycle*), which is the next iteration of the simulation. If multiple lines with an assignment to a signal are executed *in the same simulation cycle*, then any event on the event queue is deleted and is replaced by the event generated by the last signal assignment (a slight over-simplification, but it will do for now).

Comment: In the code examples, `case2` should be `when case2 =>`

Comment: @scary_jeff I was adopting the argot used in the original question.

Comment: `argot`; had to look that up, good word! I guessed that, but thought using the real syntax would be more useful to future readers. Just a suggestion.